# Firebug not hitting breakpoint even if code is executing

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, firebug, breakpoints

In some places, when I set a breakpoint, Firebug not hits breakpoints even if the code is executing. In the specific case bellow, I know that the code is executing because I write an alert that is displayed.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, it's not because the line don't have a line number in green.

Is there any reason why Firebug would not stop to the breakpoint even if code is executing?

**Edit 14-08-2012 09:23**

After been helped by some comments, I tried to add a statement "debugger" and Firebug have been stoped but instead of breaking in my javascript, it breaks into a strange file that you can see bellow. What are these files?

Just for the information, the file named "9" is my javascript but minified.

Thank you for the help.

[image]

Comment: try adding `debugger;` in line 69, that will trigger the breakpoint

Comment: I've had this scenario happen to me before, usually if firefox doesnt pick up my javascript change (maybe it caches the js file?) 

Have you tried restarting firefox

Comment: Hi @Craig! I tried to restart my computer after restarting firefox :) No luck... :(

Comment: @rsplack: do you mean the other addon for firefox named "javascript debugger"?

Comment: I think he means the command "debugger;" it throws an exception, its just to prove that the line of code is being hit, also try ctrl+f5 which will cause the cache to be refreshed with new instance of the js file(s)

Comment: Hi @Craig, thank you for the help about "debugger". I updated my question adding some details that I've found after adding the debugger statement. Have you any idea about this files?

Comment: try chrome or ie dev toolbar ? Or opera's version if you wanna be cool.

Comment: I figure out what's the problem but I don't know why the scripts are embedded. In my view, I have a bunch of code generated from a 'EditorTemplates' and in this template, I also have a reference to the javascript file that I want to debug. If I have a reference to a javascript in this template, the javascript is loaded in memory but minified into jquery like I my last screenshot. In this case, the script that is executed is not the none-minified but instead, the javascript named "9". Note that "9" is not a fixe name; it could change depending of the order of files loaded in memory.

Comment: Someone have information, article about this behavior (My last comment) ?

Comment: I found the answer in here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/firebug/qyTBf-VJov8[1-25]

Comment: He say: "The script panel tries to show you all the scripts that have been compiled by Firefox's JS engine.  Usually the script has a URL associated with it, which is what Firebug displays in the list of scripts, but sometimes, JavaScript gets compiled because of an event handler attribute, or an eval statement. In these cases, Firebug doesn't know the URL so it makes up a URL to display in the script list of the format <original_url>/<compilation_type>/seq/n

So an event handler script might look like index.html/event/seq/1 and an eval script look like index.html/eval/seq/2"

Answer (score 1):

It can happen if there's asynchronicity involved (for example, you hit one breakpoint, and before it, you invoked `setTimeout`).

Since your function is called `eventCreateOnSuccess`, I guess it's an asynchronous callback.

See my answer in the other thread: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11834880/245966

Have you put the breakpoint *only* in this one line, or also in some other lines, which are executed before it? If the former, try disabling all the breakpoints, and enable only this one - it should work fine then. Otherwise, it's really strange.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue because I was using source maps. Breakpoints set in source maps files do not trigger (unlike in Chrome). To disable source maps in Firefox, click on Gear icon in the top right corner of Firefox Dev tool, then unselect Show Original Sources. Then, set your breakpoints in original JS files.
[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fRMx.png)