# Firebug doesn't hit breakpoint in a function within a namespace

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, namespaces, firebug, breakpoints

I am reorganizing all my js introducing namespaces with a main script (using jQuery) :

```
var myapp : {
    user :   { ...  },  
    ...
    init : function() { ...}
}
```

and I load an additional js for some page like for example 'home.js', with :

```
(function(){
    $j.extend(true, myapp, { 
        _home : {
            init: function() { ...},        
            myfunc : function(prm){
                ...
            }
        }
    });
    myapp._home.init();
})();
```

Now, if I put a breakpoint in the myfunc function, and call myapp._home.myfunc(); in the console, Firebug doesn't hit.

Is it normal ? How can I have a breakpoint there ?

**Edit:** I am wrapping the _home script into a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the "debugger" keyword

```
function test(variable) {
  for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    if(i == 5)
      debugger;
  }
}
```

Comment: But the myfunc is called (I added `return "test"; ` to myfunc. and I get the "test" as a result of myfunc).

Comment: we agree that you have activated your script-panel in firebug, right?

Comment: I am loading the additional script asynchronously. May it be an issue for Firebug ? (knowing that I can see the script _home.js in the script panel.

Comment: Indeed that was due to the asynchronous load... If I load 'normally' (with <script src='home.js'></script>) I can see it **and** I can hit the breakpoint. Using my script to load asynchronously (home made), I can see the script in the panel **but I can not** hit breakpoints.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :-)

Answer (score 0):

Searching about asynchronous call and firebug issues, I found this thread

[firebug (1.10.1) suggests javascript is not confined to a single thread in firefox (13.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802771/firebug-1-10-1-suggests-javascript-is-not-confined-to-a-single-thread-in-firef)

which gives some details.

Conclusion : I will include my files in the 'traditional' way for debugging ;)